# Got Warnings after enabling Proguard for Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, proguard

I enabled Proguard for Xamarin Android app and got these warning:

```
can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [classes.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
can't write resource [.readme] (Duplicate zip entry [classes.jar:.readme])
can't write resource [.readme] (Duplicate zip entry [classes.jar:.readme])
```

How to solve them ?!

Comment: Those are warnings, not errors : http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#duplicatezipentry

Comment: Yeah! Thanks,I have updated the question, Any way to solve them ?

Comment: There are multiple `.jar`'s that each contain a `.readme` file. If you have control over the `.jar` file(s) you can remove one or more of those, but I would assume that they are coming from 3rd-party `.jar`s like Google's Android compat v4, v7, etc... and thus the answer is no to removing the warnings. If you were using Android Studio/gradle there are options to filter those duplicate resources out, but I know of no way that can be done with `Xamarin.Android` without modifying the original `.jar` files directly, which I would not recommend